# checkmarx Client Potential XSS fix

Tags: jquery, xss, checkmarx

After checkmarx scan, we got report about Client Potential XSS and
tried to fix it

We already tried the following utility to encode content but none works

```
https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify
https://github.com/ESAPI/node-esapi/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss-filters
```

The reported problem code

```
$(element).after("<label class='error' style='color: red;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+$ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML($(error).text())+"</label>");
```

I understand inject variable to html component should be carefully handled but I don't know how to meet checkmarx requirement.

Hope someone experienced can help

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution proposed by @fgb is almost right. Checkmarx seems not like concatenation when creating HTML.

The following code might not good enough, but it pass checkmarx test

```
var label = $("<label class='error' style='color: red;'>");
label.text($(error).text());
$(element).after(label);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a false positive with Checkmarx not seeing what ESAPI is doing. Is the error displayed right if it contains characters like `<` or `>`?

It may be easier to avoid creating HTML with concatenation and use the `text()` methods instead. Then you don't need the encoding. Like:

```
$(element)
    .after($("<label class='error' style='color: red;'>").text($(error).text()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I confirmed characters are properly encoded but your suggest code still not pass checkmarx. I wonder how checkmarx test and report this problem